# RCTWebSocket - Ignoring return value of function declared with warn_unused_result attribute

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am currently working on a React Native project. Literally, out of nowhere, I just began to experience this error in XCode.

I've done a good amount of Googling to no avail. Has anyone experienced this? More importantly, does anyone have a resolution?

Answer (score 7):

### To make this clear:

- Select the error
- click the build settings tab
- look for Apple LLVM 8.0 Custom Compiler Flags
- select the 'other warnings' entry
- select each flag, click the `-` to remove them.

This makes the build work.

Answer (score 5):

After further investigation, I found an solution here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8584

After I removed Custom Compiler Flags under Build Settings for RCTWebSocket, all was well.

As an aside, I began to get errors in RCTScrollView related to a '_refreshControl' variable. Once I removed the underscore, all errors disappeared.

I'm not sure if/why these are related, but this was the process that I encountered that enabled me to ultimately get a successful build.

Answer (score 4):

This was the solution for me: Open the file Views/RTCScrollView.m in Xcode and change the variable *_refreshControl* to *refreshControl*. All occurrences of *_refreshControl* were already marked as errors. The new code becomes:

```
- (void)setRefreshControl:(RCTRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
  if (refreshControl) {
    [refreshControl removeFromSuperview];
  }
  refreshControl = refreshControl;
  [self addSubview:refreshControl];
}
```

Comment: Removing the build flags and changing this worked perfectly +1

Answer (score 0):

Choose **RCTWebSocket** project in your navigator and remove the flags under build settings > custom compiler flags

[image]